# выпадающий список на jQuery с checkBox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите реализовать идею, второй день бьюсь. Нужно реализовать выпадающий список из checkbox и при выборе, значения должно отображаться в input, а при снятии, удаляться.

Реализовал вот так, вроде работает, но если поставить несколько инпутов, то в итоге при клине на одном, выпадают списки у всех, и если черкнуть, то прикидываться количество значений чекетов на все инпуты

```
<div class="col-3" id="col1">
                  <div class="headVolumeGroup" id="headVolumeGroup1">
                    <input class="effect-1" data-parameter="1"  data-id="volumeGroupsStringReturnException1"
                           type="text" autocomplete="off"
                           id="volumeGroupsStringReturnException1"  />
                    <span class="focus-border"></span>
                    <p class="multiSel" id="multiSel1" hidden></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="listVolumeGroup" id="listVolumeGroup1">
                    <div class="mutliSelect" id="mutliSelect1">
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <input type="checkbox" value="120" />120</li>
                        <li>
                          <input type="checkbox" value="138" />138</li>
                        <li>
                          <input type="checkbox" value="150" />150</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-3" id="col2">
                  <div class="headVolumeGroup" id="headVolumeGroup2">
                    <input class="effect-1" data-parameter="2" data-id="volumeGroupsStringReturnException2"
                           type="text" autocomplete="off"
                           id="volumeGroupsStringReturnException2"  />
                    <span class="focus-border"></span>
                    <p class="multiSel" id="multiSel2" hidden></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="listVolumeGroup" id="listVolumeGroup2">
                    <div class="mutliSelect" id="mutliSelect2">
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <input type="checkbox" value="120" />120</li>
                        <li>
                          <input type="checkbox" value="138" />138</li>
                        <li>
                          <input type="checkbox" value="150" />150</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

и сам JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".col-3 .headVolumeGroup input").on('click', function() {
  $(".col-3 .listVolumeGroup ul").slideToggle('fast');
});

$(document).bind("click", function(e) {
  var $clicked = $(e.target);
  if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("col-3"))
    $(".col-3 .listVolumeGroup ul").hide();
  });

 $('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on("click", function() {
   var title = $(this)
      .closest(".mutliSelect")
      .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
    .val(),
  title = $(this).val() + ",";
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
  var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + "</span>";

  $(".multiSel").append(html);
  var val = $(".multiSel").text();
   $(".col-3 .headVolumeGroup input").val(val);
} else {
  $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
  var val = $(".multiSel").text();
  $(".col-3 .headVolumeGroup input").val(val);
}
});
});
```

пытался атрибутами прикидывать нужный id и некий num, далее слеплять, чтобы в итоге брался у каждого свой инпут. Но в итоге переменными не удалось прокинуть значения.

Вот так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var element;
var id;

 $(".col-3 .headVolumeGroup input").on('click', function() {
    id = this.getAttribute("data-parameter"); 
    element = this.getAttribute("data-id"); 
  $("#col" + id + " #listVolumeGroup" + id + " ul").slideToggle("fast");
 });
 $(document).bind("click", function(e) {
  var $clicked = $(e.target);
  if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("col-3"))
  $("#col" + id + " #listVolumeGroup" + id + " ul").hide();
 });

 $('#mutliSelect' + id + ' input[type="checkbox"]').on("click",    function() {
var title = $(this)
    .closest("#mutliSelect" + id)
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
    .val(),
  title = $(this).val() + ",";

if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
  var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + "</span>";
  $("#multiSel" + id).append(html);
  var val = $("#multiSel" + id).text();
  $("#col" + id + " #headVolumeGroup" + id + " #" + element).val(val);
} else {
  $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
  var val = $("#multiSel" + id).text();
  console.log(element);
  $("#col" + id + " #headVolumeGroup" + id + " #" + element).val(val);
}
});
});
```

Естественно не сработало как нужно.

Помогите плиз, сам пока на начальных этапах в изучении  jQuery. На js смог сделать, но хотелось бы понять, как это на jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странно конечно что на чистом js у тебя получилось, а переписать на jQuery нет. 
Все немного проще) И для взаимодействия с input'ами не стоит использовать события клика, лучше пользоваться специальными событиями, такими как: input, focus, blur, change.
Вот набросал небольшой пример, надеюсь правильно понял твою задумку.

```js
$(document).on('focus', '.show-list', function() {
 var $input = $(this);
 var $checkList = $input.siblings('.check-list'),
    $checkBoxes = $checkList.find('.check-list__checkbox');
      
  $checkList.show();
  
  $checkBoxes.on('change', function() {
    var inputText = '',
        checkStatus = 0;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < $checkBoxes.length; i++) {
     if ($checkBoxes.eq(i).is(":checked")) {
       checkStatus++;
        
        if (inputText === '') {
         inputText = $checkBoxes.eq(i).val();
        } else {
         inputText += ', ' + $checkBoxes.eq(i).val();
        }
        
        $input.val(inputText);
      } else if (checkStatus === 0) {
       $input.val('');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper + .wrapper {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.check-list {
  display: none;
}

.check-list ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="show-list">
  <div class="check-list">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="120" class="check-list__checkbox" />120</li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="138" class="check-list__checkbox" />138</li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="150" class="check-list__checkbox" />150</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="show-list">
  <div class="check-list">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="120" class="check-list__checkbox" />120</li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="138" class="check-list__checkbox" />138</li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="150" class="check-list__checkbox" />150</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Но да js я смог именно передачей id сделать, а тут я именно не смог связать id и нужный блок. Я и вешал на фокус, но в итоге у меня получалось двойное срабатывание, то есть в итоге увеличивалось в два раза значение при каждом клике. Спасибо большое, буду изучать код и смотреть где ошибся:)

Comment: оказалось все на много проще. Еще моя беда была в том, что я не подумал даже, что документ начать можно было с события, а не с ready. Спасибо еще раз

Comment: Получилось реализовать что задумал, понял свои ошибки, осталось доделать скрытие списка по клику на импуте или в поле, но это уже мелочи, главное было понять как получить отдельно инпут.

Comment: @Владислав `$(document).ready` ты правильно использовал, это совсем разные вещи, я через документ просто накинул обработчик на инпут.

Comment: я вот как раз про это не знал, почитал. теперь доработал скрипт на скрытие списка и если какие-то значения из списка уже внесены в инпут, то он автоматически чекин их в списке.